# group-by attribute doesn't allow "dot" (angular ui-select)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

Is there any work around for this issue?

In their example, they just group people by `country` property.

But in real projects, it may become more complicated. For example, in a multilingual website, it may require `country.lang` instead of just `country`. (`lang` may change when users switch their site language)

I tried with a group function but no luck, the choices are not rendered again when the language variable changes

Please have a look at this plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/tEwsvMHGu7QqwAsFt8iW?p=preview), file: `index.html`, line `75`.

Comment: your demo seems works fine, i change your repeat binding to `peopleAsync` cause the data is more comprehensive, and the group works well, what's the problem?

Comment: @jarvanJiang What do you mean? Don't you see `people` and `peopleAsync` has different data structure? Can you give the updated plunkr? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: your demo seems to work. could you be more specific

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm your demo used `people`, but all three data has same start letter group, therefor you can't see if group by is work properly, so i change to `peopleAsync`, then your `someGroupFn` is worked. So you can just group data in `someGroupFn`.